# Editor not replying to emails long time after submission

Tags: paper-submission, editors

My problem is the following.

I submitted a paper to a journal of Elsevier almost a year ago.

Although I have written many times asking about the status of the submission, my emails have been systematically neglected and I have not received any news since last November of 2018.

In view of the long time lapsed, I wrote to the editor asking him to sure a date for an answer so that I can free myself of the commitment acquired with him so that I can submit the paper to another journal.

One more time the email was neglected.

The results of this submission have been already presented in congresses with very good reception of the audience. Now, due to a long time lapsed, I am at risk of missing them.

What can I do?

Comment: What news did you get in November 2018?

Comment: @Allure He informed me that he didn't have yet a referee's report.

Comment: Even if it is a good journal, they can nowadays have problems finding reviewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it these two scenarios are the most likely:

1. They feel they're being pestered by you and so are ignoring your emails. This would apply if by "many" times you mean you wrote them so many emails that they got annoyed. It's also more likely to be the case if, in your field, the average review times are up to 1 year (e.g. mathematics).
2. The other possibility is that the editor is busy/inactive, and isn't paying much attention to the journal.

Your options are:

- Wait and see what happens.
- Write to the journal office and ask for a status update. Check the journal's website and see if they have a contact email. If they refer you back to the editor then the chances of #1 having happened increase (although it's also possible that the desk editor is simply not very motivated and is passing everything on to the editorial board).
- You can also ask the editor-in-chief instead of the handling editor.
- Withdraw and submit elsewhere. If you choose this route, look around at the editorial management system and see if there's a withdraw option.

Comment: I also asked the editor-in-chief and the email was also ignored.